# UI Pan Gesture don't work

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

Pan gesture added at view of my ViewController. It must to detect, what cell of collectionView i was tapped, and move it. All works good, but sometimes Pan Gesture caught "begin" and "changed" events and didn't catch any end-events (need to catch "ended" event). I attempted to catch all events, but when I get out my finger - nothings going on. Pan gesture added at Storyboard and connected with action.

Here is code of my action:

```
    //--------------\\
    var translitionSensitivity : CGFloat = 1.0 
    let thresholdWhenSensitivityWillGrow : CGFloat = self.view.frame.width / 4
    let sensitivityMultiplier : CGFloat = 15 
    let animDuration = 0.4
    //--------------\\


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let indexPath = self.getCellAtPoint(sender.location(in: self.view))
        if indexPath == nil { return }

        var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath!) as! DetailCardCollectionViewCell
        if self.activeCell != nil { cell = self.activeCell } else {self.activeCell = cell}

        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.collectionView)
        var howMuchOffseted : CGFloat = 0.0

        if sender.state == .began
        {
            self.lastTranslationPos = 0
        }

        if sender.state == .changed
        {
            if cell.mainViewTrailingConstraint.constant >= thresholdWhenSensitivityWillGrow
            {
                translitionSensitivity += (cell.mainViewTrailingConstraint.constant - thresholdWhenSensitivityWillGrow) / sensitivityMultiplier
            }
            else
            {
                translitionSensitivity = 1
            }

            howMuchOffseted = (self.lastTranslationPos - translation.x) / translitionSensitivity
            self.lastTranslationPos = translation.x

            cell.mainViewTrailingConstraint.constant += howMuchOffseted
        }

        if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled || sender.state == .failed || sender.state == .possible || sender.state == .recognized
        {
            print("ended")
            if cell.mainViewTrailingConstraint.constant > thresholdWhenSensitivityWillGrow / 2
            {
                cell.mainViewTrailingConstraint.constant = thresholdWhenSensitivityWillGrow
                UIView.animate(withDuration: animDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                cell.mainViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: animDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
            }

            self.activeCell = nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Pan gesture added at Storyboard and connected with action" Added to _what_?

Comment: @matt, IBAction

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What was the pan gesture recognizer added _to_ "at Storyboard"? Provide enough info for someone to _reproduce_ the problem you are having.

Comment: @matt, i mean that I added Pan gesture not in a code

Comment: That's right. And you added it _to_ a view. _What_ view?

Comment: @matt view of my ViewController. Also I attempted to add gesture at collection view, but nothing result.

Comment: So I guess my question is: if you want to make _cells_ respond to a gesture, why do you not add the gesture recognizer to each _cell_?

Comment: Also what is this "trailing constant" stuff? Cells are not positioned by autolayout. The collection view layout positions them.

Comment: @matt I think that it will take more memory:)

Comment: @matt "trailing constraint" is a constraint of my cell's view.

Comment: I see (I think). So you do not want to drag the cell — you want to drag something inside the cell. Am I right about that?

Comment: @matt yes! somthing like "swipe to delete" in collection view

Comment: Okay, I repeat my earlier suggestion. You are making things way too difficult for yourself. Using code, put the pan gesture recognizer on the _view you want to be able to drag_ (in each cell). Or, even better, wrap this view in a horizontal scroll view, so that it will automatically be draggable (because a scroll view is scrollable). — I'm going to give that as an answer, because I feel very strongly about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are making things way too difficult for yourself. Using code, put the pan gesture recognizer on the *view you want to be able to drag* (in each cell). Or, even better, wrap this view in a horizontal scroll view, so that it will automatically be draggable (because a scroll view is scrollable) — that is how most home-brewed swipe-to-delete implementations work.